# Entity "GenericArguments[2] System.SIngle" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity

Can anyone help me to understand what this error message (below) is trying to tell me?

I have code that successfully writes records to my SQL Server database table, and code that reads it back. But I've been struggling to create code to DELETE records from this same table.

An example of what I am trying to do:

```
public void DeleteUnfinishedTransaction(int uftID)
{
var uft = _dataContext.UnfinishedTransaction.Where(t => t.ID == uftID).FirstOrDefault();
if (uft != null)
{
_dataContext.UnfinishedTransaction.DeleteOnSubmit(uft);
}

_dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've reworded this several different ways but when the "SubmitChanges" line is reached, this error is always thrown:

> GenericArguments[2], 'System.Single', on
>   'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.PropertyAccessor+Accessor`3[T,V,V2]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'V2'.

I've been searching for information on this error to try to understand it and have been coming up empty-handed.

A little more info: this is a web application for which the 'metadata' (e.g., EDML, etc.) has been lost or destroyed, so all of the data access code which is normally auto-generated has to be written "by hand." I may have made a mistake somewhere else in the code -- the code above is just what triggers the actual error.

Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for days before posting a question here, but less than two hours after I did, I backed into the root of the problem.

In the code defining the structure of the fields in the 'UnfinishedTransaction' object (above), there were some unfortunate conversions being attempted between C#'s "single" and "double" data types, and SQL Server's "float." Once I fixed that I stopped getting the error and all appears well.

I'm surprised that those conversions were not problematic on 'Save' and 'Select,' only on 'Delete.'